# How to interpret the CPU_LOAD and FREE_MEM on sinfo --format "%O %e" output

Tags: slurm

What is the interpretation for CPU_LOAD (%O) and FREE_MEM (%e) --format arguments, of sinfo command?

I have a couple of jobs and they have CPU_LOAD beteween 0 and 25, is this the *load avg* that we know in `uptime` command?

What is the unit used for FREE_MEM?

The manual of sinfo can be found here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html

But the documentation is vague

> %O CPU load of a node
>
> %e Free memory of a node

As a matter of example I'm using this command

```
 sinfo --format "%O %e"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this the load avg that we know in uptime command?

Yes.

> What is the unit used for FREE_MEM?

Megabytes